# How can I set my div's width based on its child width?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a thread view (CHAT inbox) like UI using HTML and CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/7mbaksvj/

My issue is the width of the div. It's coming as a fixed width. But I want it to be auto, based on the length of the content inside, and able to grow to a max of 80% of the width.

I'm using two classes `.bubble-right` and `.bubble-left` to align them using margins.

```
.bubble-left {
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    background: #D5D9DB;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.bubble-left:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 17px 12px 0;
    border-color: transparent #D5D9DB;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -12px;
    left: -17px;
    top: 60%;
}
.bubble-right {
    margin-top: 1%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    background: #5EC979;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.bubble-right:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 0 12px 17px;
    border-color: transparent #5EC979;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -12px;
    right: -17px;
    top: 60%;
}
```

**When CSS float property is used to align left and right**, width is proper, but **all my divs are getting aligned in a single row.**

I'm looking for **a solution in CSS and HTML.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the background-color to the P inside your .bubble-(left|right)

I.E.:

```
.bubble-left, .bubble-right {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

.bubble-left {
    margin-right: 20%;
}

.bubble-right {
    margin-left: 20%;
}

.bubble-left p, .bubble-right p {
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: auto;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

.bubble-left p {
    background: #D5D9DB;
    float: left;
}

.bubble-right p {
    background: #5EC979;
    float: right;
}

.bubble-left:after, .bubble-right:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -12px;
    top: 50%;
}

.bubble-left:after {
    left: 0;
    border-width: 12px 17px 12px 0;
    border-color: transparent #D5D9DB;
}

.bubble-right:after {
    right: 0;
    border-width: 12px 0 12px 17px;
    border-color: transparent #5EC979;
}
```

Comment: With your suggestion, Width issue is fixed but right div are center aligned. http://jsfiddle.net/7mbaksvj/4/

Comment: Fair enough. I've editted my suggestion. This should work without having to change your html.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block;` is your answer here, but you need a way of keeping the blocks from lining up on a row. I would wrap each `.bubble-left` and `.bubble-right` in another div, then:

```
.bubble-right, .bubble-left { ... display: inline-block; ... }
```

#### Edit

Oh, also on `.bubble-right`, on each container `div`, add `text-align: right;`.

Comment: hey i tried your suggestion. but it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/7mbaksvj/3/.  left side is fine. but right side alignment is again has some issues

Comment: @sedhuait I see it. I updated my answer... make all the right elements right-aligned. You could also just make `.bubble-right { float: right; }` but that involves some clearfixes, so easiest is the above. Lots of ways to handle this. Fewest lines is best in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to float the bubbles to the left or right depending on their class, and importantly clearing the floats on the parent. Do not give a fixed width or margin of 20% as you have given. Just give a `max-width` of 80% to keep it within limits.

This is how you could do it: (*Demo Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/hL5z0f37/*)

**Snippet**: (*only relevant portions of code*)

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.container {
    background-color: #eee; 
    margin: 8px; 
    height: 80%; width: 50%; /* this height and width is only for demo snippet */
    overflow: auto;
}

.bubble { width: 100%; clear: both; } /* clear the floats here on parent */
.bubble p {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px; margin: 8px 12px;
    max-width: 80%;  /* this will make it not exceed 80% and then wrap */
    position: relative;
}
.left p { background-color: #ccc; float: left; } /* floated left */
.right p { background-color: #3c3; float: right; } /* floated right */

/* classes below are only for arrows, not relevant */
.left p::before {
    content: ''; position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0; left: -8px; top: 8px;
 border-top: 4px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid #ccc;
 border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.right p::after {
    content: ''; position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0; right: -8px; bottom: 8px;
 border-top: 4px solid transparent;
 border-left: 8px solid #3c3;
 border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bubble left"><p>msg</p></div>
    <div class="bubble left"><p>long message</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>ultra long message which can wrap at eighty percent </p></div>
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>very long message</p></div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make left bubbles look like you want you can make them `float: left`. For right ones you should float them right. For all bubbles you should use `max-width: 80%` and use `clear: both`.

```
.bubble-left {
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    background: #D5D9DB;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7mbaksvj/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table;` to make width of elements is following the content inside and make element `float:right` / `float:left` and use `clear:both;` to make sure next element in the next line

#### Demo :  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0p8rvn0/3/)

example for right content :

```css
.bubble-right {
    margin-top: 1%;
    position: relative;
    display:table; /* make display as table */
    float:right;   /* set float right */
    clear:both;    /* clear both */
    pading-right: 16px; /* add padding */
}

.bubble-right:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 0 12px 17px;
    border-color: transparent #5EC979;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -19px;  /* re-positioning */
    right: 0px;       /* remove right position */
    top: 60%;
}
```