# CSS child element to inherit background of parent's parent - iMessage in CSS

Tags: css, imessage

A client has asked me to emulate the iMessage chat bubbles, which have a fade effect as you scroll, i.e. the top bubble is a slightly lighter shade of blue than the bottom bubble.

The simplest way I could think of doing this (without javascript) was for a base background to have a gradient, and then the child elements on top have a transparent background so as you scroll you get the gradient background in the children. This works, but filling in the white space around the bubbles has proven to be a real challenge.

Essentially I am wondering if there is some magical css class that lets me apply a background on the child that ignores the first parents background and inherits the one beneath that.

For example:

```
<div class="gradient">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="child">
          I'm a bubble
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.gradient {
    height: 500px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 100%);
}
.container {
    height: 500px;
    /* I want this background to be around the child */
    background: white;
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    /* I want the gradient background here NOT the container background */
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

EDIT: We have tried overlaying the container with the gradient class but this breaks scrolling and being able to click buttons underneath.

We've also tried borders, pseudo elements etc but resizing usually adversely affects this.

This is for a cross browser desktop and tablet site so has to be somewhat responsive.

Many thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Do you want the whole element to fade, or only the background colour?

Comment: Hi, literally the designers have copied the scroll effect of iMessage if you have access to an iPhone. So just the background colour will change, text will remain white. Bottom bubble would be dark blue, top bubble would be light blue for example. As you scroll it stays the same. Around the bubbles is a static colour e.g. white.

Answer (score 1):

> The simplest way I could think of doing this (without javascript) was
>   for a base background to have a gradient, and then the child elements
>   on top have a transparent background..

1. If you are content with just having a fade effect (*i.e. gradient*), then just do it the other way around. Otherwise you will fall into the trap of then identifying the currently top bubble on every scroll and then change the styles. Very quickly this will become a nightmare for you.

Keep one element on top and give that a gradient so that the top-most bubbles are visible through this element via transparency and thus fade out as scrolled.

Easiest would be to have your markup like this:

```
<div class="wrap"> <!-- The outermost wrapper for entire chat -->
    <div class="container"> <!-- The chat window container -->
        <div class="bubble"><p>msg</p></div> <!-- individual chat bubbles -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then position an element on top of it via CSS:

```
.wrap::after {
    content: ''; position: relative; display: block; 
    top: -100%; left: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 16px); height: 64px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

This will put the gradient on top of the chat wrapper window and the bubbles will scroll underneath it inside the `container`.

*Below is a demo derived from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27486767/1355315*

**Demo Snippet 1:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.wrap { margin: 8px; height: 80%; width: 50%; overflow: hidden; }
.container {
    background-color: #eee; 
    height: 100%; width: 100%; 
    overflow: auto;
}
.bubble { width: 100%; clear: both; } /* clear the floats here on parent */
.bubble p {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px; margin: 8px 12px;
    max-width: 80%;  /* this will make it not exceed 80% and then wrap */
    position: relative;
}
.left p { background-color: #ccc; float: left; } /* floated left */
.right p { background-color: #33c; color: #fff; float: right; } /* floated right */

/* classes below are only for arrows, not relevant */
.left p::before {
    content: ''; position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0; left: -8px; top: 8px;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.right p::after {
    content: ''; position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0; right: -8px; bottom: 8px;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #33c;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.wrap::after {
    content: ''; position: relative;
    top: -100%; left: 0;
    display: block; width: calc(100% - 16px); height: 64px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(242,242,242,1), rgba(242,242,242,0));
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container">
    <div class="bubble left"><p>msg</p></div>
    <div class="bubble left"><p>long message</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>ultra long message which can wrap at eighty percent </p></div>
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>very long message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble right"><p>one more message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>another message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>yet another message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Edit

> emulate the iMessage chat bubbles, which have a fade effect as you
>   scroll, i.e. the top bubble is a slightly lighter shade of blue than
>   the bottom bubble.

2. If you are looking to emulate exactly the behaviour of iMessage, then you have to remember that there is no fade effect. The top bubble has a different color (close to cyan) from the rest of the bubbles. There is no shading or fading.

In order to do that, you will have to resort to Javascript because CSS has no way of determining which bubble is currently at top based on scroll. Just wire up the `scroll` event of the container, and check the position of the bubbles and change the color accordingly.

Below is a pure Javascript example (*no jQuery*) based on the demo above.

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/oop2dazy/1/**

**Demo Snippet 2:**

```js
var cw = document.getElementById('chatWindow'),
    threshold = 64;
cw.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var bubbles = cw.getElementsByClassName('right');
    [].forEach.call(bubbles, function(elem) {
        var top = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
        if (top < threshold) { elem.classList.add('faded'); }
        else { elem.classList.remove('faded');}
    });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
.wrap { margin: 8px; height: 80%; width: 50%; overflow: hidden; }
.container {
    background-color: #eee; 
    height: 100%; width: 100%; 
    overflow: auto;
}
.bubble { width: 100%; clear: both; } /* clear the floats here on parent */
.bubble p {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px; margin: 8px 12px;
    max-width: 80%;  /* this will make it not exceed 80% and then wrap */
    position: relative; transition: background-color 0.5s; 
}
.left p { background-color: #ccc; float: left; } /* floated left */
.right p { background-color: #33c; color: #fff; float: right; } /* floated right */
/* classes below are only for arrows, not relevant */
.left p::before {
    content: ''; position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0; left: -8px; top: 8px;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.right p::after {
    content: ''; position: absolute;
    width: 0; height: 0; right: -8px; bottom: 8px;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid #33c;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}
.bubble.faded p { background-color: #39c; }
.bubble.faded p::after { border-left: 8px solid #39c; }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div id="chatWindow" class="container">
    <div class="bubble left"><p>msg</p></div>
    <div class="bubble left"><p>long message</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>ultra long message which can wrap at eighty percent </p></div>
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>very long message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble right"><p>one more message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>another message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
    <div class="bubble right"><p>yet another message</p></div>    
    <div class="bubble left"><p>lorem ipsum</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This will solve your problem of obscured top portion of the chat window. This will allow touch-scrolling from the top portion and also interactions on the bubbles will not be obstructed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. We thought of and tried this solution too. The issue with it is as the gradient layer is over the top of the container layer, you can't click on this area (sometimes we have buttons) and also if you try to scroll over this area it doesn't allow to scroll etc. With the gradient they want it would have to cover probably 2/3rd's of the height so it's not really viable. We are going the js route for now and will play with performance as we go along. I'll edit the question. Many thanks again

Comment: @sam9046: I agree that touch-scrolling will be a problem and also if you have interactions with the bubbles, then that is a problem too. I have updated the answer to add a simple Javascript-based solution. But with many bubbles, the performance might take a hit.